# Controller's $scope Not Being Initialized

Tags: angularjs

As far as I know the **resolve** property of a $stateProvider is used to initialize the properties of its controller.

```
//Config
.state('init', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/Init.html',
    controller: 'InitController',
    resolve: {
        InitData: function(initService, tabService) {
            var data = initService.mapData();

            tabService.field1.IsABC = data.field1.IsABC; //returns the value true (Boolean)

            return true;
        }
    };


//Controller (InitController)
app.controller('InitController', ['$scope', 'tabService', function($scope, $tabService) {
    $scope.IsABC = $tabService.field1.IsABC;
}]);
```

In my example above, if tabService.field1.IsABC has been assigned a value of true, should not be **$scope.IsABC** under the InitController get the same value?

Comment: Show the code you have on your tabservice please.

Comment: In the tabservice, this is how field1 is initialized:

var field1 = {};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set value of "field1" in service properly...

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router'])
    .factory('myDataFactory', function ($http) {
    var field1 = {"IsABC":false};  //default false;
    return {

        set: function (value) {
             field1.IsABC = value;
            return x;
        },
        get: function () {

            return field1;
        }

    };
})
```

set in resolve :

```
 resolve: {
                    backendData: function (myDataFactory, $stateParams) {
                        return myDataFactory.set(true);
                    }
                }
```

Get in Controller :

```
.controller('homeController', function ($scope,myDataFactory) {

    $scope.hello = myDataFactory.get();
    console.log( $scope.hello);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value in the resolve would appear in the controller under "InitData". Inject "InitData" in your controller to get "true"... Also check the name of your service. It's "tabService", isn't it?

Comment: Yes I understand that but the value that I need is one from tabService.field1 which should have a value of true after being assigned the value of data.field1. And yes, the name of the service is tabService.